WordPress - Access $context of parent block within block pattern
Issue
I have a setup using Gutenberg blocks via ACF. One of these blocks is a Group block which has the following context:
"providesContext": {
    "acf/groupData": "data"
}

I am then using <InnerBlocks /> inside the group block template file.
Each of the blocks that can be nested in this group block have a value of:
"usesContext": ["acf/groupData"]

This works perfect and the group values are passed into the $context array for use within the inner blocks.
However, if I add a Synced Pattern block inside this group block, the context is lost and acf/groupData is not part of the $context array.
Hoping someone can help, would be great if there's a way to pass down the group context into synced patterns.
Tried
I've had a look around to see if there's any hooks relating to when patterns are created to see if I can pass the context through there but no luck.
I also tried creating a function that would grab the post content, parse the blocks and try and get the group block from there, however, the block ID's aren't returned when using the post content, only the block name and attributes etc.

Does the <InnerBlocks> have an allowedBlocks attribute? And if so, are all of the pattern blocks on that list? Have you tried dumping the block data before save or while editing? You might find help on the plugin support forums: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/advanced-custom-fields/

What happens when you detach the block from the synched pattern? My guess is that the block won't work with a context as a synched pattern.

@admcfajn It does, yes. However, the pattern isn't created in the code, it's created in the editor view within WP Admin. So I can't include this within allowedBlocks since many of these can be created on the fly.

@EmielZuurbier Yeah it works fine when detached, I think because once detached, it's then a direct descendant of the group block, so the context is there. It only seems to be an issue with synced patterns.

I meant the blocks used in the patterns, not the pattern blocks themselves. Sounds like a tricky issue that could change at any time. Wish I had more time for this one, good luck! Have you checked the source for both SyncedPatterns and the ACF blocks you're working with? Code for both and roadmaps for improvements is available to read online.

@admcfajn Ah no worries, I'll take a look! Thanks for your help

No worries, the only thing I can think of that might work, without reviewing your code in depth.... Would be to save the contents of the groups to an attribute on parent acf/scf on save, so instead of depending on gutenberg to save the child-blocks, intercept the json for the child blocks and save it to an attribute on the parent block. and wordpress.stackexchange might help. Normally wordpress stackexchange doesn't allow questions about 3rd party plugins, but since .org has branched acf, your question is likely a good fit

@admcfajn Ah, yes, that's a nice idea. That might be the solution I end up choosing unless I can find something else. Much appreciated!

Unfortunately, Synced Patterns (previously known as "Reusable Blocks") do not inherit context by design, because of how they are intended to be used across posts/pages and templates so they do not rely on context being provided.
Reviewing your scenario, the Group block provides context of "acf/groupData" to InnerBlocks in the Editor, which works, although block context cannot be saved. Each of your nested blocks within InnerBlocks consume "acf/groupData" and if they are rendered dynamically, they can use the provided context on the frontend, eg:
render.php
<?php
/**
 * @see https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/docs/reference-guides/block-api/block-metadata.md#render
 * $attributes (array): The block attributes.
 * $content (string): The block default content.
 * $block (WP_Block): The block instance.
 * 
 * Example render callback for child/nested block contained within InnerBlocks
 * that receives context from Parent
 */
?>

<div <?php echo get_block_wrapper_attributes(); ?>>
    <?php echo $block->context['acf/groupData']; // prints "data" ?>
</div>

If you then saved this as a Synced Pattern, a warning Undefined array key “acf/groupData” is triggered as the parent blocks' context does not exist to the Synced Pattern because Synced Patterns are actually saved as a custom post type (wp_block) in the database to be reused/included in other content.
Possible Workaround
Instead of Synced Patterns, I would:

Define a Template for InnerBlocks in the Group block that lists the nested/child blocks required (and any default values for each).
Register Block Variations (if required) of the Group block that varies the InnerBlocks Template which removes the need for Synced Patterns while maintaining the context between Parent - Child.
Use Dynamic Blocks for the nested/child blocks to enable it "acf/groupData" to be rendered on the frontend (see render.php example above).


Hi S.Walsh, thanks for the response, I managed to figure out a way using pattern overrides which I will post as an answer to this question soon, so have managed to keep the use of synced patterns with parent context.

The context loss with Synced Patterns is a known limitation because patterns are treated as separate entities. Here are two potential solutions:

Pass context via pattern attributes:

register_block_pattern(
    'namespace/pattern-name',
    [
        'title' => 'Pattern Title',
        'attributes' => [
            'groupData' => [
                'type' => 'object',
                'default' => null
            ]
        ]
    ]
);

Then modify your group block to pass data as attributes:
$block_content = str_replace(
    '<InnerBlocks',
    '<InnerBlocks groupData="' . esc_attr(wp_json_encode($context['data'])) . '"',
    $block_content
);


Use WordPress's block context filter:

add_filter('render_block_context', function($context, $parsed_block) {
    if ($parsed_block['blockName'] === 'core/pattern') {
        $parent_context = wp_get_block_context();
        if (isset($parent_context['acf/groupData'])) {
            $context['acf/groupData'] = $parent_context['acf/groupData'];
        }
    }
    return $context;
}, 10, 2);

The first approach is more reliable but requires pattern modification. The second is global but may have edge cases.

Hi Chris, thanks for sending these solutions over. The first option isn't possible since the pattern isn't being registered in the code and instead in the admin editor. The second option is close to the solution I ended up using (Will post soon), although there isn't a function for wp_get_block_context(), so unfortunately wasn't able to use that approach.
Thanks for the help though!

I figured it out! I'm posting here for any future developers.
The other answers to this question weren't possible since the synced patterns being created aren't being registered through the code and instead in the Admin Editor using the options menu for blocks.
What I ended up doing was:

Hook into the render_block_data filter. Check if the block type is core/block (Pattern) and has a parent block. If so, set the 'content' attribute onto the block in question. The pattern block renderer will treat this as overriding data which is then supplied to the block context. For some reason the $context array within the block template won't pass through the pattern/overrides straight away, which is where the next step helps.
Hook into the render_block_context filter. Check if the $context array contains 'pattern/overrides'. If so, set the acf/groupData key (What we usually have available for non-pattern blocks) equal to the pattern/overrides data. This makes the data available to use within the block template .

/**
 * Since synced patterns lose the context of the parent block, we need to pass the parent data as a pattern override.
 * By using 'content' as the key, the core/block (Pattern) renderer will treat this as overriding data for the block.
 * This is then passed to the block context in the render_block_context filter.
*/
add_filter('render_block_data', function($parsed_block, $source_block, $parent_block) {
    if ($parsed_block['blockName'] === 'core/block' && $parent_block) {
        $parsed_block['attrs']['content'] = $parent_block->parsed_block['attrs']['data'];
    }

    return $parsed_block;
}, 10, 3);

/**
 * The pattern/overrides is available here in the context array but for some reason, not in the template.
 * If the block has pattern overrides supplied, add them to the block context using the acf/groupData key.
 */
add_filter('render_block_context', function($context, $parsed_block, $parent_block) {
    if (!empty($context['pattern/overrides'])) {
        $context['acf/groupData'] = $context['pattern/overrides'];
    }

    return $context;
}, 10, 3);

